# Printing Previous Record in Crystal Reports if Null Encountered

Tags: crystal-reports-2010

I have a report in which i have a formula (in crystal syntax) balance which is inserted in details section.formula is like:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Global CurrencyVar Balance;
 if {table.cr}>0 or {table.dr} > 0 then
Balance:= Balance+ {table.cr} - {table.dr};
Balance
```

I want the report to print previous record for balance if table.cr and table.dr is null.Any help ???

Comment: any one please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Balance is the value that you are calculating locally...

To the extent I understand you need to use the previous value of `{table.cr}` and `{table.dr}`

```
if ISNull({table.cr}) and ISNULL({table.dr}) then
Balance:= Balance+ Previous({table.cr}) - Previous({table.dr});
Balance
```

Let me know if this is not your requirement

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion.But i did it through my vb code.Anyway thanks a lot.